# free():invalid size, but no new() or free() was called - SQLite3 using C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

Hi I am playing around with sqlite3 using C++. I am storing an array as BLOB and try to extract it from the database. However, when I select data from the database I got free():invalid size error after the function selectTable() finishes and before main() finishes. So I am a bit confused.

The output on the command line is

```
selectTable func
Opened database successfully
before finalzie
after close DB
free(): invalid size
Aborted
```

Below is backtrace from gdb and the code

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff717a801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff71c3897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, 
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff72f0b9a "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff71ca90a in malloc_printerr (
    str=str@entry=0x7ffff72eeda0 "free(): invalid size") at malloc.c:5350
#4  0x00007ffff71d1e2c in _int_free (have_lock=0, 
    p=0x7ffff7de5990 <_dl_init+864>, av=0x7ffff7525c40 <main_arena>)
    at malloc.c:4161
#5  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x7ffff7de59a0 <_dl_fini>) at malloc.c:3124
#6  0x0000555555555b48 in main ()
```

```
    int main() {
      const char* dir = "testBLOB.db";
      sqlite3* DB;
      //createDB(dir);
      //createTable(dir);
      //clearTable(dir);
      for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        //insertTable(dir);
      }
      cout << "selectTable func" << endl;
      selectTable(dir);
    
      cout << "Out of selectTable func" << endl;
      return 0;
    }
    
    static int createDB(const char* s) {
      sqlite3* DB;
      int exit = 0;
    
      exit = sqlite3_open(s, &DB);
    
      if(!exit) {
        //cout << "opened db" << endl;
      }
      sqlite3_close(DB);
    
      return 0;
    }
    
    static int createTable(const char* s) {
      sqlite3* DB;
      string sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test("
      "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
      "name TEXT NOT NULL, "
      "vector BLOB"
      ");";
      try {
        int exit = 0;
        exit = sqlite3_open(s, &DB);
        char* messageError;
        exit = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.c_str(), NULL, 0, &messageError);
        //cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
        if(exit != SQLITE_OK) {
          cerr << "Error creating table" << endl;
        } else {
          sqlite3_close(DB);
        }
      } catch (const exception & e) {
        cerr << e.what();
      }
    
      return 0;
    };
    
    
    static int insertTable(const char* s) {
      sqlite3* DB;
      long double nums [100] = {63.3448897849,56.5751700134,75.6611442415,44.4839808971,12.1012110357,39.8311006389,55.4628689524,44.1856083913,31.8941372232,36.7439371495,64.1919152947,46.6041307466,16.8129922477,26.4797506344,33.0942127905,87.7671523992,76.4743660304,26.895728291,71.6418628151,39.4279836297,33.1511476055,21.9412133656,49.2985876344,54.7288568945,61.7644413811,39.5360580159,48.2049240243,15.0657890486,74.8453755862,3.9697162327,46.3309272981,3.6967671205,29.4109279366,35.2237159178,71.2944696538,83.2668276235,8.6042287278,29.018178646,53.9090162771,74.1875874704,13.362141479,85.534882156,46.1570578637,16.6535624939,60.4663891357,46.4002226626,43.5334234645,5.9192657242,6.4233909782,70.9674985846,16.7364288218,6.140383666,1.6295357671,41.5132888558,7.0105695897,93.7402324433,67.9067125381,79.2202639865,73.9691802822,83.7211616527,95.1748897322,77.6210081594,52.6691899363,45.9668407426,30.0850082804,99.8853106577,44.4116175004,66.7492926269,80.344211132,2.9125625332,13.1282558744,77.1323341686,31.6479987137,12.0439293147,52.34792652,10.0973593886,11.1281788415,42.3558223361,26.0832770714,78.8802218674,65.7943757958,39.4931075012,62.3669620437,40.5895497709,75.5671730948,32.0576337297,97.9215110968,9.9871548843,46.6131220896,11.0937537323,59.9746432863,25.2756546914,39.1604177152,21.5325516688,55.5211448299,29.0247732257,10.4586600007,53.0534949121,77.3997550972,48.2887426956};
    
      int rc = sqlite3_open_v2(s, &DB, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE,NULL);
      if(rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    
      } else {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO test (name, vector) VALUES ('test', ?)";
        try {
          sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
          rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, sql.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL);
    
          if(rc != SQLITE_OK) {
            cerr << "Error preparing stmt" << endl;
          } else {
            rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt,1, nums, 1600, SQLITE_STATIC);
            if(rc != SQLITE_OK) {
              cerr << "bind failed" << endl;
            } else {
              rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
              if(rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
                cerr << "no" << endl;
              }
            }
    
          }
          sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        } catch (const exception & e) {
          cerr << e.what();
        }
      }
      sqlite3_close(DB);
      return 0;
    };
    static string selectTable(const char* s) {
      sqlite3 *db;
      int rc;
    
      /* Open database */
      rc = sqlite3_open(s, &db);
    
      if( rc ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return(0);
      } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
      }
    
      sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
      /* Create SQL statement */
      const char* sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
      if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0) != SQLITE_OK)
      {
          return 0;
      }
    
    
      int result = 0;
      while (true)
      {
          result = sqlite3_step(stmt);
          if (result == SQLITE_ROW)
          {
    
              // Get the size of the vector
              int size = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 2);
              // Get the pointer to data
              long double * p = (long double *)sqlite3_column_blob(stmt,2);
              // Initialize the vector with the data
              vector<long double> data(p, p+size);
              allVects.push_back(data);
          }
          else
          {
              //cout << "not SQLITE_ROW" << endl;
              break;
          }
      }
    
      cout<< "before finalzie" << endl;
      sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
      
      while(sqlite3_close(db)!= SQLITE_OK) {
        cout << "not ok" << endl;
      }
    
    cout<< "after close db" << endl;
    
    }
```

Comment: sqlite uses dynamic memory.

Comment: BTW, I don't see the bug when looking at the code but I can't debug too carefully in my head.. I am suspicious of the use of opening and closing the database in each function instead of opening it one time for the life of the program.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you. I checked the documentation and it says Sqlite has no memory leaks and that made me more curious..Basically I had another version of program that stores array as string delimitated by comma and it worked without free() warning. That other version also opens and closes database in each function, so I was thinking it's something wrong with the BLOB functions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself. It's because the return type of my function selectTable() is string, however inside function it does not return a string. It's weird that my compiler did not complaint about it tho...

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue is observed when return type of a function is bool and nothing is returned from that function. Even when return type is bool, call stack shows "invalid free" performed on a string. This was quite misleading.

Behavior is undefined when return statement is missing in a function except main().
In my scenario -

- Crash is observed when the code is built with g++ version 8.3.0 on debian10(buster slim).
- Same code works fine when it is built with g++ version 6.3.0 on debian9(stretch slim).

Developer will be able to detect this during the compile time based on the compiler options enabled. for eg: -Wall

Please note that this is independent of SQLite usage.